# C# DOM XML Parser displays 1 entry instead of 2

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a simple XML reader that reads an XML file with DOM Approach. The problem is, I have two Products in this particular XML file but it only displays the second product (refer to InvoiceItem box). I'm pretty sure I've made a stupid mistake somewhere but I just don't see it.

Results:
[image: Result of parsing]

Source code: http://pastebin.com/Rh1PF92N

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Invoices>
  <Invoice ID="I1">    
    <InvoiceDate>21/06/2016</InvoiceDate>
    <SellerID>Supp001</SellerID>
    <BuyerID>WCS1810</BuyerID>
    <OrderID>O1</OrderID>
    <InvoiceItem>
      <Product ID="R1">
        <ProductName>8GB RAM King</ProductName>
        <Description>8GB RAM King Brand</Description>
        <Capacity>8GB</Capacity>
        <Quantity>150</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>100</UnitPrice>
      </Product>
      <Product ID="R2">
        <ProductName>4GB RAM King</ProductName>
        <Description>4GB RAM King Brand</Description>
        <Capacity>4GB</Capacity>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>50</UnitPrice>
      </Product>      
    </InvoiceItem>
    <ShippingCharges>5</ShippingCharges>
    <InvoiceTotal>205</InvoiceTotal>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach (XmlNode node2 in productList)` you iterate through both products but the code which populates `invoiceItem` and adds it to `invoiceItems` is outside of the foreach loop, so when the foreach loop finishes you are adding only the last element from the loop to `invoiceItems`.
Put all this code inside the product foreach

```
invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem();
invoiceItem.InvoiceID = node.Attributes[0].Value;
invoiceItem.ProductID = prodID;
invoiceItem.Description = description;
invoiceItem.Capacity = capacity;
invoiceItem.Quantity = qty;
invoiceItem.UnitPrice = unitpx;
invoiceItem.TotalPrice = (qty * unitpx);
invoiceItems.Add(invoiceItem);
```